# What is wrong in this code i tried in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE sales ( "customer_id" VARCHAR(1) ,"order_date" DATE ,"product_id" INTEGER );

INSERT INTO sales ( customer_id ,order_date ,product_id ) VALUES ( 'A' ,'2021-01-01' ,1 );
( 'A' ,'2021-01-01' ,2 );
( 'A' ,'2021-01-07' ,2 );
( 'A' ,'2021-01-10' ,3 );
( 'A' ,'2021-01-11' ,3 );
( 'A' ,'2021-01-11' ,3 );
( 'B' ,'2021-01-01' ,2 );
( 'B' ,'2021-01-02' ,2 );
( 'B' ,'2021-01-04' ,1 );
( 'B' ,'2021-01-11' ,1 );
( 'B' ,'2021-01-16' ,3 );
( 'B' ,'2021-02-01' ,3 );
( 'C' ,'2021-01-01' ,3 );
( 'C' ,'2021-01-01' ,3 );
( 'C' ,'2021-01-07' ,3 );
```

Comment: How and From what IDE are you call those commands ? Btw, At a first glimpse,  INSERT statement are wrong except for the first one. Moreover, you should format the date literals properly such as date'2021-01-07'

Comment: Commas vs semicolons within the INSERT statement, assuming Oracle supports multiple VALUES clauses in a single INSERT statement.  Otherwise, not repeating the `INSERT` clause for the subsequent VALUES clauses.

Comment: Get rid of double quotes when working with Oracle and save yourself of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Since

- you are using double codes in the column name and Oracle expecting
  case sensitive name
- only the first statement conforms the INSERT statement syntax, while
  the rest should be fixed

So, the correct statements for all of those current lines would like to be the following:

```
INSERT INTO Sales
  ("customer_id",
   "order_date",
   "product_id")
VALUES
  ('A',
   date'2021-01-01', -- date literal is fixed
   1);
```